Add custom marks to a slider
I noticed in the System Settings cursors with marks, but not regular as the step parameter of a SwiftUI Slider() would allow.
For example, here there are three custom marks: "Off", "Small" and "Large".

Is it possible to reproduce this without using .overlays?

What's wrong with using overlay? What else do you not want to use?

I'm using the swiftui-sliders library to display custom sliders. Using an overlay would display as its name suggests something above the slider, including the bar to move...

So how about showing the marks using .background instead?

It's a good idea, but it doesn't look very clean...
